# Join a collection to an existing aggregate query mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongodb-query

I have the following collection structures in my mongodb database.

**Orders**

```
[  
   {  
      "_id":"order_abcd",
      "name":"Order 1"
   },
   {  
      "_id":"order_defg",
      "name":"Order 2"
   }
]
```

**Session**

```
{  
   "_id":"session_abcd"
   "orders": [ ObjectId("order_abcd"), ObjectId("order_defg") ]
}
```

**Transactions**

```
{  
   "_id":"transaction_abcd"
   "id_session" : ObjectId("session_abcd")
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is a dataset that looks similar to this

```
[  
   {  
      "_id":"order_abcd",
      "name":"Order 1",
      "transaction":"transaction_abcd"
   },
   {  
      "_id":"order_defg",
      "name":"Order 2",
      "transaction":"transaction_abcd"
   }
]
```

I do not have any input data other than a `start date` and an `end date` which will be used to filter orders, the query is mostly for reporting purposes so in effect I am trying to generate a query to fetch all orders between a given time period and attach the transaction id for each order to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use couple of `$lookup` (analogous to join with 2 tables in SQL) with `$unwind` at each stage to finally `$project` the key-value pair that is desired.

```
db.Session.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "Transactions",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "id_session",
      as: "transaction_info"
    }
  },
  { $unwind: "$transaction_info" },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "Orders",
      localField: "orders",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "order_info"
    }
  },
  { $unwind: "$order_info" },
  {$project:{
    _id:"$order_info._id",
    name:"$order_info.name",
    transaction:"$transaction_info._id"
  }}
]).pretty();
```

Which gives an output:

```
{
    "_id" : "order_abcd",
    "name" : "Order 1",
    "transaction" : "transaction_abcd"
},
{
    "_id" : "order_defg",
    "name" : "Order 2",
    "transaction" : "transaction_abcd"
}
```

> The unwind stages are used to explode the lookup and then cherry pick fields at final project stage.

**++UPDATE++**

Another option that probably can help reduce the 2nd stage lookup records since `$match` on dates of `Orders` can be applied to pass on filtered docs for next stage.

```
db.Session.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "Orders",
      localField: "orders",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "order_info"
    }
  },
  { $unwind: "$order_info" },
  {
    $match: {} //filter on "order_info.property" (i:e; date,name,id)
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "Transactions",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "id_session",
      as: "transaction_info"
    }
  },
  { $unwind: "$transaction_info" },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: "$order_info._id",
      name: "$order_info.name",
      transaction: "$transaction_info._id"
    }
  }
]).pretty();
```

Comment: This works but looks like it would be a massive task since mongo would have to go through all the `session` collections and then join them with their respective `transaction` document and only then be able to probably run a match to filters `orders`. Is there a way to run the match early on in the pipeline to reduce the number of documents mongo has to perform a lookup on?

Comment: @JudeFernandes I'm not sure how much this'll help unless we can benchmark it, since we don't really have filters on `Transactions` or `Sessions` other way could be joining the collections `Session->Order` then have a `$match` for `Orders` by dates as u mentioned and then `$lookup` to `Transactions`.

Comment: Thanks this does seem like it could work, I will wait a little while longer to see if there are any other answers else mark yours as the correct one.